# do something after first view controller appears

Tags: swift

I have a View Controller with a button..
This button calls a "Present as Popover Seague" to a second view controller.

The second view controller has a close button with this function:

```
@IBAction func exit(_ sender: UIButton) {
   self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now I would like to do something in the first controller, after the second Controller is dismissed.

In the first view controller I tried this functions:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   print("viewDidAppear")
}
    
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   print("viewWillAppear")
}
```

but no console log will shown.
Where is my mistake?

**FirstViewContorller**

```
import UIKit


class firstVC: UIViewController {
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        //ERROR
        secondVC.dismissCompletion = {
            print("dismissCompletion")
        }
    }
    
}
```

**SecondVC (popover)**

```
import UIKit

class secondVC: UIViewController {


    var dismissCompletion: (() -> Void)?

    // EXIT POPOVER
    @IBAction func exit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: dismissCompletion)
        
    }
  
}
```

Comment: have you tried delegates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewDidAppear()` method of the main view controller won't be called because of the popover presentation style you use. If you choose to present the second view controller full screen - those methods will fire.

If we're sticking with the popover, the first thing you need to do is in your second view controller, the one that's being presented, add a property for a closure that will be executed upon its dismiss:

```swift
class PopoverViewController: UIViewContoller {
    var dismissCompletion: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func exit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: dismissCompletion)
    }
}
```

And in your main view controller you define what needs to be done upon the popover's dismiss:

```swift
popoverViewContoller.dismissCompletion = {
    // do stuff
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I assume you've setup the segue in your storyboard. I also assume that in your storyboard you've given the view controllers their respective class names:

[image]

This is what your code should look like:

```swift
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        secondVC.dismissCompletion = {
            print("Popover dismissed")
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var dismissCompletion: (() -> Void)?
    
    @IBAction func exit(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: dismissCompletion)
    }
}
```

Please note the classes naming and the way I got the `secondVC` instance.

Comment: the linke `popoverViewContoller.dismissCompletion = {}` gives a error:
Instance member 'dismissCompletion' cannot be used on type 'popoverViewContoller'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: @Ghost108 you have to declare the property in the class that represents your popover view controller (the one where your exit IBAction is), then set the completion for an instance of that class. The naming in my answer is random, I just showed you the structure. If you do it correctly there shouldn’t be an error.

Comment: I putted the `var dismissCompletion: (() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func exit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: dismissCompletion)
    }` into my secondViewController

and in the viewdidload of my firstviewcontroller: `secondVC.dismissCompletion = {
            // do stuff
        }`

Error: `Instance member 'dismissCompletion' cannot be used on type 'secondVC'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`

Comment: @Ghost108 Are you sure that your secondVC is of type SecondViewController? Could you please post your code somewhere to see the complete picture?

Comment: So have I, please see the full answer.

Comment: that's it ! Thank you so much :)